# Windows 10 WITHOUT updates

Tags: windows-10, powershell, updates

I would like to have the **full control on the Windows 10 updates**. I have already searched on the Internet and I have found this Github repository: https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10

I need to know if those PowerShell scripts are enough or if I need to do some extra stuff.

Comment: what would be the exact reason ? If you're on a network or the Internet, its highly recommended you do the updates. Going on a network without updates is highly risky.

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as updates can be, Microsoft intentionally made it near impossible t disable automatic updates in Windows 10 for security reasons.  I believe it's possible to disable automatic updates on the student or enterprise versions of Windows 10 but its not advisable to do that and much more difficult on other editions.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because you indicate you only believe it's possible to disable updates, you are not even sure it's possible, a quality answer contains verified information.  You also failed to identify this question as a duplicate of an existing question.  It also contains grammatical mistakes.  Most importantly, the answer also reads more like a comment, than an actual solution to somebody's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Windows 10 Education/Enterprise.
You get options to *ignore* updates.

If you can't do that, Windows 10 Pro lets you *postpone* updates.

Powershell scripts can be a bit risky. If you **MUST** have a free solution, try [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_update_minitool.html) which allows you to select which updates can be installed and which can be blocked.

But be warned;

**Any unofficial methods may invalidate your Windows License or break Windows!**

Comment: Why was I downvoted?

Comment: I guess this person wants an answer that solves their problem without money or being told that what they're doing is wrong.

Comment: OP wanted a question, I gave him the answer. That's how superuser works, right?

Comment: inconvenient answers are frowned upon apparently

Comment: In any case, don't let it discourage you too much. Welcome to the site. =)

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 - Upgrading to Windows 10 Enterprise/Education isn't an acceptable answer to the question proposed in my opinion.  It also doesn't answer the question proposed about the PowerShell script in question.  You also failed to identify this as a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: And how do I identify that?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 - If you had taken the time to write a detail response, and explained in detail, how to accomplish what the author wanted you wouldn't have received a downvote from me.  The question would still be a duplicate in my opinion but there wouldn't have been anything wrong with your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Fair enough.